# The invasion of my world

Tags: invasion

My world has been invaded by a highly intelligent extraterrestrial species from other worlds.
This species is also highly advanced in technology and civilized in a way that it  out competes my world's technology.

It has been visiting my world for several years and some believe that our existence could have been their creation.

**Now my question is** "what could this invasion result into ?"

Remember this question is not a duplicate of this [Fighting Off an Alien Invasion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4492/fighting-off-an-alien-invasion)

Comment: Question is too open-ended to be answered. One answer would be "start with every alien invasion story ever written". You'll need to tailor this more narrowly to get useful replies.

Comment: Yeah, this is way too broad. There are too many things we'd need to know before we could answer. What is their technology level ("highly advanced" doesn't cut it)? How much knowledge do they have of us? What's their invasion strategy like? What's their physiology like? What are their weaknesses? What's their society like? Why are they invading? Is it to enslave the population? To strip-mine the planet? For the glory of the Emperor? Some Manifest Destiny ideology? We would need to know so much in order to say how it could go, and you've given us basically nothing to go on.

Comment: Could I legitimately post the script of 'Independence Day' as an answer to this one?

Comment: Please clarify what your asking?

Answer (score 2):

If the aliens are biologically compatible it could lead to interbreeding and biological diversification.

Comment: You're right.They can do biological research to make it happen besides that,frequent experimentation is also bound to happen on humans.